# Modify email order notification in Prestashop

Tags: html, prestashop

I would like to modify the email order notification in prestashop slightly and I don't where to start. The email templates are written in HTML and whenever I modify them the email comes out blank.

Here is the code:

```
<tr>
    <td style="border:none;padding:7px 0">
        <table class="table table-recap" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:100%;background-color:#fff"><!-- Title -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="border:1px solid #DDD!important;background-color:#fbfbfb;font-family:Arial;color:#333;font-size:13px;padding:10px">Reference</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid #DDD!important;background-color:#fbfbfb;font-family:Arial;color:#333;font-size:13px;padding:10px">Product</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid #DDD!important;background-color:#fbfbfb;font-family:Arial;color:#333;font-size:13px;padding:10px">Unit price</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid #DDD!important;background-color:#fbfbfb;font-family:Arial;color:#333;font-size:13px;padding:10px">Quantity</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid #DDD!important;background-color:#fbfbfb;font-family:Arial;color:#333;font-size:13px;padding:10px">Total price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="color:#777;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important">
                        {items}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="conf_body">
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" colspan="4" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important"><strong>Products</strong></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important">{total_products}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="conf_body">
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" colspan="4" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important"><strong>Discounts</strong></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important">{total_discounts}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="conf_body">
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" colspan="4" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important"><strong>Gift-wrapping</strong></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important">{total_wrapping}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="conf_body">
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" colspan="4" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important"><strong>Shipping</strong></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important">{total_shipping}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="conf_body">
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" colspan="4" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important"><strong>Total Tax paid</strong></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important">{total_tax_paid}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="conf_body">
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" colspan="4" class="total" style="color:#555454;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important;font-size:18px;font-weight:500;font-family:Open-sans, sans-serif"><strong>Total paid</strong></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#fbfbfb" align="right" class="total_amount" style="color:#333;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important;font-size:21px;font-weight:500;font-family:Open-sans, sans-serif">{total_paid}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to remove all pricing information. Some price info is easy to identify and delete, e.g. {total_paid}, but there is also the itemized price info in the section of code below, in which all the info is just bundled together in {items}. How do I modify this?

```
            <td colspan="5" style="color:#777;padding:10px!important;border:1px solid #DDD!important">
                {items}
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you're looking at is a simple `Swiftmailer` email template file, meaning it can only **replace** variables like `{items}`.

To output a dynamic list of products, you need a more powerful templating language which can **loop over** a list of products. That's why the HTML for the list of products is compiled at:

```
themes/default-bootstrap/mails/en/order_conf_product_list.tpl
```

Your theme and language ISO code in this path may be different.

This is wehre you actually edit the rows `<tr>` or products. If you remove a cell, don't forget to remove column title cell too `<th>`!

If your emails lose some styling when they're saved (e.g. they become 100% in width) it may be that you need to install this override:

https://gist.github.com/gskema/d3f62431965dbb5c8cdb04da97c9dc77

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I create a new order email template so that two are sent out?

Comment: @Dorian821 You should post a new question first